# Prestashop, checkout module hides all content

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I recently bought a One Step Checkout / One Page Checkout module.

And testing with register account, checkout worked out fine!

But here is the weird behavior.. when trying to check out without logged in(as guest), it puts all page elements to `display:none`

[image]

So first I thought It could be an error, but when enableing DEVMODE it didn't show any errors, no php nor js errors. It just hides all elements.

What could be the issue?

Comment: there must be some JS or CSS coming into action for a specific condition and making the elements invisible. You are supposed to find the same.

You should report this to the developers of the module

Comment: @Wolfack I have all ready reported this issue, I haven't been replayed for two days, just looking for some kind of fast solution